# MongoDB + PHP : Like operater query not fetching any results from db

Tags: php, mongodb

Looking to fetch db results, In databse query `like` wise operator used.

```
$regex = new MongoRegex('/$search/i');  
$where = array('contact_name' => $regex);       
$users = $collection->find($where);
```

I am not sure, What went wrong with syntax. Please suggest, I am not able to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

If `$search` is supposed to hold your search criteria, it will not get evaluated within a single-quoted expression.

```
$regex = new MongoRegex("/$search/i");
```

should work here.

As `$where` works differently in Mongo, I'd advise to use `$query` as variable name here.

Comment: $rs = $collection->find(array("contact_name" => new MongoRegex("/^$search/")));

This what my query..Which i placed

Place the same as u mentioned, But admin has changed the query line